# Do we need certifications for device designed for 240V

Tags: pcb-design, mains, certification

I have completed the design of a circuit board where the mains 240V can be connected with screw terminals.
This is just a sub-assembly unit. This would normally be used in industrial environment.

Are there any kind of certifications needed for selling such unit that uses these 'high' voltages? How is the safety aspect of the product covered?

Comment: What country it will be sold in is important.

Comment: I would say that *some* certification will be needed for most countries.

Comment: Certainly the box it goes into will need to be certified in most places.  As already stated, whether the board does varies from country to country.  Plan on at least some redesign if you weren't designing it from the ground up to pass certification.

Comment: This will be for the United Kingdom.

Comment: Also there will be no box. The client will only buy the assembled PCB.

Comment: Start with CE marking and look up the directives that may apply such as LVD and EMC.

Comment: If producing subassembly then CE should not apply does it? My only question is for a sub-assembly designed for 240V. Are there any cert required for it?

Comment: The certification might be requested by the final product manufacturer, as the final product needs to be certified as stated above. And that certification will be much simpler if the sub-assemblies are certified.

Comment: Thank you. What about the 240V then?

Comment: @Noel 240V comes under the LVD requirements (Low voltage is anything less then 1000V AC), for a subassembly probably more of a quality of implementation, marketing and insurance issue then a certification one in the EU rules sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sub assembly does not need to be certified, but the final equipment does need to. This means that your board also needs to comply to at least LVD, EMC and RoHS directives. If it violates those, the final equipment will fail the certification tests.

The low voltage directive and its harmonized standards cover the safety issues you need to consider

Comment: EMC is highly dependent on how the system as a whole is put together, hard to certify that for a subassembly except under specific conditions.... Same thing goes for SOME bits of the LVD. Now if you sell a subassembly and it turns out to be impossible for the system integrator to get the system to pass because of something stupid your board does, well, they going to be pissed, but I don't believe there is actually a CE issue on your board as such.

Comment: Yes, it is not illegal to sell such a board. Just bad for business.